# A hacky way of getting a HH:MM:SS time string in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm doing the following in js to get a time string:

```
(new Date()).toTimeString().substring(0, 8)
```

All I needed was this string (definitely don't' require anything like moments.js). When googling didn't see anyone doing it this way. Is there any serious disadvantages\possible issues with what I'm doing here?

Comment: Interesting thanks for the info I had no idea. Do we know of any browsers that actually do implement this differently or is it that they just could if they wanted to without violation?

Comment: Very good to know thank you. Could you answer my question with this info so I can mark it as the answer? I'd consider the info you provided a complete answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the [`toTimeString` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.4) is specified in ECMAScript 5:

> The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the “time” portion of the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.

A browser or environment could legally produce a format that would break your approach, because the result of `toTimeString` is entirely implementation-dependent. For example, not using leading zeroes, or omitting seconds, or using AM/PM instead of 24-hour time, etc.

I don't know if *all* environments use the same format, but I'd assume most choose ISO 8601 formatting because there are other specified functions (like `toISOString`) that require ISO formatting anyway. In terms of *responsibility of fault*, in the rare event that some environment comes along that doesn't work with your code, I'd say your code would be fault for relying on nonstandard behavior.

By contrast, the return value of `toISOstring` is [standardized as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (that's always a literal `T` and, in the case of UTC, a literal `Z`), but it might not help you here because it always uses the UTC time zone, instead of local environment time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use split to get the Time in the HH:MM:SS Format.
So with `.toTimeString()` you get a string but this shouldn't be bad.
There are no serious disadvantages by your/my method.

```
alert(new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0]);
//Because newDate().toTimeString() results 'HH:MM:SS GMT...' 
//split it and take the first item of the array
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Someone answered my question with that method. They tested it and found it negligibly slower: http://jsperf.com/split-vs-substring-so. Is split just safer to use? I don't think its particularly more readable.

Comment: So I don't think that this speed differences might be noticed. My method (and the of the other guy) are just another method to get that, what you want. You can use both of them.